# How to configure StructureMap for different Import Types

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have currently 2 file types I can import.  I have an interface of type IImportFileAction.  Then I have 2 classes that inherit this interface named ImportGPX and ImportTCX.  Import GPX imports a .gpx file and ImportTCX imports a .tcx file.  I pass the filename in the constructor of these two classes.  How would I initialize StructureMap so that if the files extention is gpx the GetInstance will return the ImportGPX and vice versa for TCX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Jeremy's post on conditional object construction](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/19/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas/). Afterwards you may find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965933/structuremap-conditional-use) useful as an example.