# How to map same interface to different ConcreteClasses with StructureMap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

When Controller1 is being created, I want that IService will be mapped to ConcreteService1 and IPageService to ConcretePageService1

And when Controller2 is created, I want that IService will be mapped to ConcreteService2 and IPageService to ConcretePageService2

How I can initialize ObjectFactory so that the above will work?

Mean while I initialezed ObjectFactory this way:

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {  
         x.For<IService>().Use<ConcreteService1>();
         x.For<IPageService>().Use<ConcretePageService1>();
    });
```

But this ALWAYS maps **ConcreteService1** to IService and **ConcretePageService1** to IPageService  regardless of controller type

```
public class Controller1 : Controller
{
    public Controller1(IService service, IPageService pageService)
    {
    }
}

public class Controller2 : Controller
{
     public Controller2(IService service, IPageService pageService)            
     {         
     }
}

public interface IService 
{
}
public class ConcreteService1:IService 
{
}
public class ConcreteService2:IService 
{
}

public interface IPageService 
{
}
public class ConcretePageService1:IPageService 
{
}
public class ConcretePageService2:IPageService 
{
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's just an isolated registration you can use named instances to map a specific instance to each controller.

```
For<IService>().Add<ConcreteService1>().Named("service1");
For<IService>().Add<ConcreteService2>().Named("service2");            
For<IPageService>().Add<PageService1>().Named("pageService1");
For<IPageService>().Add<PageService2>().Named("pageService2");            
For<Controller1>().Use<Controller1>()
  .Ctor<IService>().Is(c => c.GetNamedInstance<IService>("service1"))
  .Ctor<IPageService>().Is(
    c => c.GetNamedInstance<IPageService>("pageService1"));
For<Controller2>().Use<Controller2>()
  .Ctor<IService>().Is(
    c => c.GetNamedInstance<IService>("service2"))
  .Ctor<IPageService>().Is(
    c => c.GetNamedInstance<IPageService>("pageService2"));
```

If this is a pattern that's repeated in the application you should use a [convention](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm) to map the types in order to avoid all this duplication.

Adding types named by type name is possible using a built in convention.

```
Scan(x =>
  {
    x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
    x.AddAllTypesOf<IService>().NameBy(type => type.Name);
    x.AddAllTypesOf<IPageService>().NameBy(type => type.Name);
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The StructueMap documentation is convoluted as hell and I wasn't able to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the ConstructedBy() syntax for StructureMap.

It's on this page, but I'm not sure if these are the latest docs for SM:

http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section18

I might be wrong about ConsructedBy--the docs aren't very good.  Look at the following for a similar question:

[StructureMap Conditional use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965933/structuremap-conditional-use)

Comment: I read it, but I don't understand how this answers my question or do I missing something? Thank you

Comment: Conditionals is not the way to go IMO. A convention is more likely to be a durable solution.