# structuremap instantiate different class depending on lifecycle

Tags: configuration, structuremap

What is the best way to configure structuremap to instantiate a different class depending on the lifecycle..

e.g. for IUser, when it is HTTP context, I want to instantiate a User class, if there is no Http context I want structuremap to instantiate a ServiceUser class?

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992700/how-to-map-same-interface-to-different-concreteclasses-with-structuremap