# StructureMap - How do I use multiple objects inheriting from the same interface

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

When using StructureMap I would like class A to be injected with Bar and class B to be injected with Baz.

How would I configure / setup this relationship with StructureMap?

```
public class Bar : IFoo {}
public class Baz : IFoo {}

public class A
{
   private IFoo _foo;

   public A(IFoo foo)
   {
      _foo = foo; 
   }
}

public class B
{
   private IFoo _foo;

   public B(IFoo foo)
   {
      _foo = foo;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992700/how-to-map-same-interface-to-different-concreteclasses-with-structuremap ...although I prefer this one as it's simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009156/61697) I think you need to do something like this:

```
For<IFoo>().Add<Bar>().Named("bar");
For<IFoo>().Add<Baz>().Named("baz");

For<A>()
    .Use<A>()
    .Ctor<IFoo>()
    .Named("bar");

For<B>()
    .Use<B>()
    .Ctor<IFoo>()
    .Named("baz");
```

Comment: Nice edit! I didn't realise there was a `Named` method.